cant download Play Console in Google play sore, showing something went wrong, try again
I cant download play console from Google Play Store, showing something went wrong error
I try to download the app from Google PLay Store
Actually I know the solution, I am just creating a problem, to help people, I will answer below

Guys I am answering for my own question, so I`ve tried many times to download the Play Console app from Google Play Store with my phone
And I find a solution:

In your laptop, you should have a google account that you have in your phone, so search for play console in google from your laptop
Go to the play store and press the download button, and it shows the dialog to choose device that connected into your google account, so choose the phone and download, it downloads into your phone automatically

I hope, my answer and question will help you )))
